# RxJava, How can I write test code for disposable.clear()?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito, rx-java

I am developing an Android app.
My app is based on the MVP pattern.

So when the Activity's lifecycle is terminated, the presenter's `unsubscribe()` function is called.

The `unsubscribe()` function just clear 'disposable'.
It's very simple code like below:

```
override fun unsubscribe() {
    disposable.clear()
}
```

The `unsubscribe()` function is very simple, so I have not tested it before.
But today, I just want to increase the code coverage.
So I tried to write test code for this function.

My first try is:

```
@Test
fun unsubscribeTest() {
    mPresenter.unsubscribe()
    verify(mockDisposable).clear()
}
```

But I didn't know the **`clear()`** function is the function of `CompositeDisposable` class, not `Disposable` interface.

So I cannot use it as a mock.

Comment: Why do you want to verify RxJava itself? We already test `CompositeDisposable` for you.

Comment: I just want to increase my Presenter code coverage. (Presenter.unsubscribe())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this using `disposable.size()`.

I changed the `disposable` to settable/injectable.

So the result is:

```
@Test
fun unsubscribeTest() {
    val d = CompositeDisposable()
    mPresenter.disposable = d

    assertEquals(0, mPresenter.disposable.size())

    d.add(Observable.just("").subscribe())
    assertEquals(1, mPresenter.disposable.size())

    mPresenter.unsubscribe()

    assertEquals(0, mPresenter.disposable.size())
}
```